# How to make Nhibernate Case sensitive query using QueryOver?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have a simple database with users table, it have simple admin user with

> UserName= "Admin"
>   Password="admin"

I am using NHibernate to query over this table to login form. 
Suppose the login form inserted `UserName="ADMIN"` and `password="ADMIN"` both in upper case.

The system should not allow login. However when I use the query like this

```
using (var session = NhibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
  return new List<User>
         (session.QueryOver<User>()
                 .Where(u => u.UserName == userName)
                 .And(u => u.Password == password)
                 .Future());
}}
```

The system ignores the case sensitivity and selects the user. So how can I make case **sensitive** query?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/31404628/11635 (which is doing the opposite - forcing an *in*sensitive comparison)

Answer (score 2):

We can specify `COLLATE` directly as a part of SQL column evaluation

```
session
    .QueryOver<User>()
    // expecting that user name could be any case 
    // if not, we can use the same as for password below
    .Where(u => u.UserName == userName)
    // instead of this
    //.And(u => u.Password == password)
    .And(Expression.Sql(" Password = ? COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS"
       , password, NHibernateUtil.String));
    .Future()
    ;
```

The above statement will use `Latin1_General_CS_AS` where CS means: *Case sensitive* and AS means *Accent sensitive*

Also, there is some draft of a custom *LikeExpression*, which could consume the COLLATE string as a const or from setting:

- [Nhibernate QueryOver collation without hard coded column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704229/)

Comment: isn't there any extension method to do this ?

Comment: Well, in this case, as far as I know - no. But it is easy to introduce new, custom one ;) I'd say.

Comment: I am new to Nhibernate, can you please suggest reference on how to create custom one ? Thanks

Comment: Extension methods are not about NHibernate!!! ;) these are C# world! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840413/ this link contains a draft how to do nice extension ;)

Comment: So, does my answer helped you? did you manage to get case sensitive (CA) comparison?

Comment: .And(Expression.Sql(" Password = ? COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS"
       , password, NHibernateUtil.String));   is not supported by Mysql.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach, not with QueryOver, but LINQ:

```
session.Query<User>().Where(u => SqlMethods.Like(u.Username, "something")).ToList();
```

Comment: Like has very different comparison semantics to equals, and this brings a whole set of security concerns into play

Comment: Depending on how the database is set up, this may not yield a case **sensitive** comparison.

Answer (score -1):

Or, with Criteria:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User), "u").Add(Restrictions.Like(Projections.Property("u.Username"), "something")).List<Username>();
```

Comment: Like has very different comparison semantics to equals, and this brings a whole set of security concerns into play

Comment: If my username I submit is e.g. `Ad%`, then I'll know if you have a (single) user called Admin or Administrator. This general approach can enable nay amount of user enumeration

Comment: Does that explain it sufficiently?

Comment: It was irony. Your answer is nothing but common sense, and only partial (no mention of indexes, for example).

Comment: Security issues are not ironic. For me indexing is very far behind that in terms of relevance. While you might be familiar with the tradeoffs and realise the validity of the concern, responding in this manner (be it ironic, passive agressive or genuine inquiry) does not help people coming across these answers and taking them at face value. Caveat emptor indeed :)

Answer (score -1):

Finally, QueryOver:

```
session.QueryOver<User>().Where(Expression.Sql("Username LIKE ?", "something", NHibernateUtil.String)).List<User>()
```

Comment: Like has very different comparison semantics to equals, and this brings a whole set of security concerns into play